# Voltage form at diode bridge

Tags: diodes, matlab, bridge

I want to find the output voltage of a circuit like this:

[image]

and this is my Matlab code to solve it:

```
function find_x
t = 0:0.001:10;
x0 = 0;
R1 = 90000;
R2 = 1000;
C = 0.001;
[t,x]=ode45(@rhs, t , x0);

plot(t,x);

    function dxdt = rhs(t,x)
        dxdt = -(C/R1 + C/R2)*x + C/R1*abs(sin(100*pi*t)) ;
    end
end
```

but it gives me the wrong answer, because the right answer is nearly a DC voltage.

[image]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: (R11 || R10) and C? have a time constant of 1 s, but you only ran the simulation for 50 ns. What happens if you reduce C? to maybe 10 nF or so and run the simulation for several 100 us?

Comment: I run for 10s, not 50ns
`t = 0:0.001:10;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your differential equation is not set up correctly. The basic equation to start with is

\$ I = C \dfrac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}\$

and for the resistors

\$ I = \dfrac{v}{R}\$

That means you should have something like

\$ \dfrac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t} = \dfrac{-v}{R_1 C} + \dfrac{V_s(t) - v}{R_2 C}\$

where I've buried the rectified sinusoid into the \$V_s(t)\$.

Notice that *C* appears in the denominators, not the numerators.

Also, the source only charges the capacitor through the 90 kOhm resistor, so with your current values the charge up has a time constant of 90 s. You'll want to run the simulation for 5 or 10x that time constant to see the output settle down around the steady-state value.

Comment: thanks very much, i got it. I realized this 2 minute ago and i fixed it successfully.

Comment: can you answer my question at the bottom, thanks so much.